# Changing Wso2 HTTP Method from POST to GET

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

How can i chnage the HTTP Method in wso2 esb using java class mediator
currently I am using
     mc.setDoingGET(false);
     mc.setDoingPOX(true);
I want to take a post request to ESB and then send to a webservice via GET or vice versa
but the above code is not working at all

Answer (score 5):

Use the property mediator with property name: HTTP_METHOD and http method name as the value (GET,POST etc) and scope as 'axis2'.

Comment: how to do it in class mediation

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change this property in the java class level, you may do the following:

```
msgCtx.setProperty(Constants.Configuration.HTTP_METHOD, "GET");
```